# Como retirar a string de um intervalo determinado

Tags: c++, string, substring

Olá,

Pessoal, estou relembrando programação(c++) e peguei um projetinho para fazer um de um programa que lê código de barras, grava em um vetor.Dentro de cada código lido entre os caracteres 24 e 33, possui um numero que referencia a Nota fiscal.
Eu preciso retirar esse numero e exibir o mesmo junto com o código.

Segue, o que eu já fiz:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

string cod[100];
char numnota;


int main()
{  
    string cod[100];
    cout<<"Comece aqui a ler os codigos de barra" << endl;
    int i=0;
     while(cod[i] != "0"){
         cin>>cod[i+1];
         i++;
    }

    i=0;
    while(cod[i]!="0")
    {
        cout << cod[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    numnota = cod.substr(24,33);

}
```

Comment: Aqui: `while(cod[i] != "0"){` será que não deveria ser: `while(cod[i] != \0'){`? Se você quer uma substring então `numnota` não deve ser declarado como um único caractere e sim como uma string. Como você não está trabalhando com a classe string talvez devesse usar: `strncpy(numnota, cod+23, 10);` (lembrando de corrigir a declaração de numnota).

Comment: Fala , Daniel

    Obrigado por responder.Então o while e a condição de parada, quando alguem digitar 0, indica que terminou a leitura dos codigos de barra.Tentei usar a função que disse, mas nao deu muito certo =/

Comment: Não sou o Daniel, mas o que você quer dizer é que em seu código de barras não é permitida a existência do algarismo zero? Quanto à função você acrescentou o terminador '\0' ao final?

Comment: Como você diz que está utilizando C++ então é mais fácil utilizar a função `substr` da classe `<string>`.

Comment: Na verdade, o "0" é a condição de parada do while, serão lidos os codigos de barra normalmente e qnd o usuario digitar 0,o codigo encerra a leitura.Vou tentar usar a classe que me disse

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isto (troquei os limites do substring para ter uma entrada menor):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string cod[100];
char numnota;


int main() {
    string cod[100], numnota;
    cout<<"Comece aqui a ler os codigos de barra" << endl;
    int i=0;
    do {
        cin>>cod[i++];
    } while(cod[i-1] != "0");
    i=0;
    cout << "Códigos informados:" << endl;
    while(cod[i]!="0") {
        cout << cod[i];
        numnota = cod[i].substr(4, 3);
        cout << "\t" << numnota << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando em: https://ideone.com/a5NoWG

Comment: Fantasístico, agradeço muito sua resposta.Mas poderia me explicar como funciona o codigo?Como eu disse eu estou reaprendendo e gostaria de saber como ele funciona